# cookie value are encoded in document.cookie

Tags: javascript, php, html, cookies

I have a cookie whose value is

```
emailID=a1%40a.comSEPmaths=0SEPphysics=0SEPchemistry=0SEPbotany=0SEPzoology=0SEPta
mil=0SEPenglish=0SEPpolity=0SEPgk=0SEPhistory=0
```

But `document.cookie.split('; ')` returns

```
 subs=emailID%3Da1%2540a.comSEPmaths%3D0SEPphysics%3D0SEPchemistry%3D0SEPbotany%3
 D0SEPzoology%3D0SEPtamil%3D0SEPenglish%3D0SEPpolity%3D0SEPgk%3D0SEPhistory%3D0"
```

Why is it encoded? If it not encoded , what it is? How do I get the exact value that I see under cookies tab in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

It is encoded because [only certain characters](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1.1) are allowed in the cookie value.

> ```
>  cookie-value      = *cookie-octet / ( DQUOTE *cookie-octet DQUOTE )
>  cookie-octet      = %x21 / %x23-2B / %x2D-3A / %x3C-5B / %x5D-7E
>                        ; US-ASCII characters excluding CTLs,
>                        ; whitespace DQUOTE, comma, semicolon,
>                        ; and backslash
> ```

Decode it with `decodeURIComponent`.